# Divide column data by number if row of next column contains certain context

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[Say I have a table like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl1nt.png)

How do I let column c with x divided by 20, with y divided by 30, and with z divided by 40.
I tried np.where function but I failed

Comment: Please provide the data frame as code rather image and explicitly give the desired output, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['c'][df['a'] == 'x'] = df['c'][df['a'] == 'x']/20
df['c'][df['a'] == 'y'] = df['c'][df['a'] == 'y']/30
df['c'][df['a'] == 'z'] = df['c'][df['a'] == 'z']/40
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.apply`, which will apply a given function over each row in a `pandas.DataFrame`. `df.apply` returns a new `pandas.DataFrame` object with the new data.

```py
def divide(row):
    if row["a"] == "x":
        row["c"] /= 20

    elif row["a"] == "y":
        row["c"] /= 30

    elif row["a"] == "z":
        row["c"] /= 40

    return row

new_df = df.apply(divide, axis=1)
```